# Are all conservative forces a central force?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, potential-energy, conservative-field

If a force is a central force and can be written as $\vec{F}(\vec{r})=f{(r)}\hat{r}$ , then it is a conservative force. But is the converse true? I mean, are all conservative forces a central force?
If no, can you please provide explanation?

Comment: Gravity on flat earth surface.

Comment: Any force that admits a potential is conservative. To get a non-central, conservative force, just pick a function $V(r, \theta, \phi)$, such that $\partial_\theta V \ne 0$ or $\partial_\phi V \ne 0$. Then $\vec F = -\nabla V$ will be a conservative, non-central force. One simple example $V=\frac 1 2 k x^2$ leads to the conservative force $\vec F = -\vec e_x kx$ which is obviously not central.

Comment: @SebastianRiese These links say that $\vec F= -kx$ is a central conservative force..... https://books.google.co.in/books?id=aVzdBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125&dq=Is+f%3D-kx+a+central+force&source=bl&ots=8uI9GSitnQ&sig=FbV6nUbhN1tzR6OwOGi7vMZDRSk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAmoVChMIz5D509rJyAIVzgSOCh0iWQjj#v=onepage&q&f=false and http://www.sfu.ca/~boal/211lecs/211lec14.pdf

Comment: @Aniket Just clicked the sfu.ca link, it talk abouk $\vec F = -k\vec x$, that is a different beast (and I would have written it $\vec F = -k \vec r$ ... using $\vec x$ for positions vectors just generates confusion in my opinion $\vec r$ is avoids this).

Comment: @SebastianRiese What kind of a different beast?

Comment: @Aniket Certainly: In 3d and spherical coordinates $\vec F = -\vec e_x kx = -\vec e_x k r \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi)$ which is neither a function of only $r$ nor pointing in the $\vec e_r$ direction as required for a central force.

Comment: @SebastianRiese So actually the same force can act either as a central or as a non-central force, depending on the constraints imposed on the force.

Comment: @Aniket The difference is, that in 1d one can identify the position vector and the $x$-coordinate, in 3d you can't. Therefore $F = -kx$ in 1d can be written vectorially $\vec F = -k \vec r = -k \vec e_r r$, which obviously fulfils the definition of a central force, in 3d the equation $F = -kx$ does not make sense $\vec F = -k \vec r$ does (and is a central force), so does $\vec F = -k \vec e_x x$ (which is not a central force, as it not even points in to/from the origin) and the two are obviously different forces. (Note that $x = \vec r \cdot \vec e_x$ is the $x$ component of the position).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30375/discussion-between-aniket-and-sebastian-riese).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question.

First, to be clear on definitions, a *conservative* field of force is one where the work done between any two fixed points is independent of the path taken; and this is equivalent (at least in Euclidean space) to saying that the work done in any closed loop is zero.

Further, the sum of any two conservative fields is also conservative.

Now take the Earth-Moon system, then we can see quite directly that the gravitational force felt by some satellite being the sum of two conservative fields is also conservative, but can't be central to some fixed point: close to the moon, it's directed towards its centre and close to the earth it's directed to its.